# Differentiate square matrix $VV^T \in R^{n \times n} $ over rectangular matrix $V \in R^{n \times r}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to differentiate $f = logdet(L)$ by $V$ where $L = VV^T$.

The thing that I know is $\frac{df}{dv_{ik}} = tr(L^{-1} \frac{dL}{dv_{ik}})$, 
where ${\{\frac{df}{dV}\}}_{ik} = \frac{df}{dv_{ik}}$.

The problem is the upper one in $\frac{dL}{dv_{ik}}$ is a square matrix but the down one is a rectangular matrix. How can i derive the solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matrix calculus, the chain rule is not your friend. The main problem is that the gradient of a matrix with respect to another matrix is an awkward, higher order tensor.

It's much easier to work with differentials, since the differential of a matrix behaves like an ordinary matrix.

Let's start with the differential of $L$ 
$$\eqalign{
 L &= VV^T \cr
dL &= dV\,V^T + V\,dV^T \cr
}$$
We can use this to find the differential of your function 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log\det L \cr
df &= d\log\det L = d\,{\rm tr}\log L \cr
   &= L^{-T}:dL \cr
   &= L^{-T}:(dV\,V^T + V\,dV^T) \cr
   &= (L^{-1}+L^{-T}):dV\,V^T \cr
   &= 2L^{-1}V:dV \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial V}
 &= 2L^{-1}V = 2(VV^T)^{-1}V = 2(V^T)^+ \cr
}$$
In the preceding, $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, and a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,A:BC={\rm tr}(A^TBC)$.

The properties of the trace give rise to many rules for rearranging the arguments of a Frobenius product, such as 
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T = BC:A \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am confused about the process $dtrlogL = L^{-T}:dL$. $dtrlogL = trdlogL = tr(L^{-1}dL)$? Can it be applied to the general case?

Comment: @NuriKim In the general case we have $$\eqalign{d\,{\rm tr}(f(L)) &= f'(L)^T:dL\cr &= {\rm tr}(f'(L)\,dL)}$$ where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ and both are applied element-wise to their matrix arguments.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: The functions are applied matrix-wise, not element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Here $n<r$ and $rank(V)=n$. One has

$Df_V:H\in M_{n,r}\rightarrow Df_V(H)=tr((VV^T)^{-1}(HV^T+VH^T))$ and

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial V_{i,k}}=tr((VV^T)^{-1}(E_{i,k}V^T+VE_{k,i}))$.